# For him vs to him vs him

Tags: pronouns

What is correct:
I am buying **him** a car.
I am buying **for him** a car.
I am buying **to him** a car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English ditransitive verbs, and transitive verbs with beneficial objects, allow two patterns:

> verb direct-object preposition indirect-object

and

> verb indirect-object direct-object.

So your first is grammatical, the other two are not (or at least, are not idiomatic)

> I am buying a car for him.

however, is perfectly normal, and identical in meaning to your first sentence.

> ?I am buying a car to him.

is odd, and I can't think of a context in which it could occur. *Buy* is not inherently ditransitive, so the meaning of an indirect argument would normally be a beneficiary, so *for him* is expected rather than *to him*.

Answer (score 2):

"I am buying him a car." would be correct.